# adding a class to an anchor based on specific text in that anchor jquery

Tags: jquery, html, css

New to jquery and would appreciate some help.

my markup looks something like this:

```
<dl>
    <dt>colors</dt>
    <dd><a>red</a></dd>
    <dd><a>green</a></dd>
    <dd><a>blue</a></dd>
</dl>
```

Let's just say I wanted to add a specific class only to the anchor with the text "green". How would I go about that?

Thanks very much

Comment: Just in case there are people out there looking to add a class to all of the elements based on the text in them: http://jsfiddle.net/lollero/5GYYu/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [:contains selector](http://api.jquery.com/contains-selector) will return partial matches like `green` will match `green`, `lightgreen` or `darkgreen`, so most of times my choice is to use [.filter()](http://api.jquery.com/filter)

```
$('dl a').filter(function(){
    return $.trim($(this).text()) == 'green'
}).addClass('newclass')
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use addClass() with function as parameter too:

```
$('a').addClass(function(){
    return $.trim($(this).text()) == 'green' ? "someClass" : ""    
});
```

Comment: I don't really see this as shorter or better in any way, using something like text() would probably be shorter, and not very readable either -> `$('a').text(function(_,txt) {if (txt == 'green') $(this).addClass('go');});` -> http://jsfiddle.net/xek8x/

Answer (score 1):

You could use [`:contains`](http://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/)

```
$('a:contains(green)').addClass('myClass')
```

or a filter if you need to be more specific, case insesitive etc.

```
$('dd a').filter(function() {
    return $(this).text().toLowerCase() == 'green';
}).addClass('myClass');
```